# errors while installing openjdk-7 jre

Tags: java

I was trying to install `openjdk-7-jre` . It has shown me errors like

```
E: Package 'openjdk-7-jre' has no installation candidate
```

so i tried with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

it works fine. Then i updated by command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

it also worked well.but after command

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

I got an error

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am pasting error messages. It is showing that download is failedand also Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
where is a mistake? what to do?

```
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|49.44.132.27|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-10-13 23:21:49 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.8-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.94-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Not so easy to find JDK7. Oracle is not officially offering anymore and it's just available in [Ubuntu repository for 14.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/openjdk-7-jre/download). You could try to download it, do a `sudo dpkg -i `command and `sudo apt install -f`to solve dependencies.

Comment: @Redbob -- the repo just gives the installer.

Comment: @anjali -- you should install jdk8 or jdk9, unless you have to have 7